# PHP Rename suing variable, throwing error

Tags: php, rename

I'm trying to use a variable with the rename() function to rename a file at the end of a function.

I'm creating the new file name like so;

```
$filenamegen = "XML_MERGE_" . date("d:h:i:s");
```

and then trying to use rename() like so;

```
rename ("F:\\a\\a\\a\\bb/tempname.xml", "F:\\a\\a\\a\\bb/" . $filenamegen . ".xml");
```

The above code is throwing the following error;

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (code: 123)
```

If anyone has any ideas of how this could be fixed it would be much appriciated!

Many thanks as always.

Comment: I think you cannot use ":" in a file name.

Comment: Colons are reserved characters, and cannot be used in a filename. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the first code line to:

```
$filenamegen = "XML_MERGE_" . date("d_h_i_s");
```

You cannot use ":" in a file name on Windows!